# Solution to sequence conversion

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I am execution below SPARQL query into qconsole, this query executed properly and returned a `solution with 2346 items`, it took `5 ms`.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";

let $distinct-ids := '
  SELECT DISTINCT ?itemId 
  WHERE {
    ?itemId <hasListName> ?listName .
    FILTER (lcase(str(?listName)) = "test")
  }
'

return sem:sparql($distinct-ids)
```

My requirement is, I want to get the result as `sequence` of items for further processing instead of `solution.`

I tried doing something like `return map:get(sem:sparql($distinct-ids), "itemId")`, and it is Woking fine but took longer time `(90 ms)` to get the result.

Is there any other way that is faster to get the sequence of items without using `map:get` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it make a difference if you specifically iterate over the results and call `map:get()` for each item instead of relying on function mapping?

```
sem:sparql($distinct-ids) ! map:get(., "itemId")
```

What about applying the `array` option to `sem:sparql()`, and then for each item get the value with `json:array-values()`?

```
sem:sparql($distinct-ids, (), "array") ! json:array-values(.)
```

Comment: Both suggested options are taking same time (80 ms - 90 ms)

Comment: You are being tricked by lazy evaluation. When the call to sem:sparql() returns, the SPARQL query has only calculated the first result row. Subsequent result rows are calculated when they are required - which is why it seems like fetching the value of one column as a sequence takes so long.